# collate Jenkins build artifacts to make another html report

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, reporting, hp-performance-center

I have approx 50 Jenkins job running HP Performance center script twice a day, which archives Performance center report that it gets from remote PC server. I am able to send these individual reports on emails but I would like to consolidate all these reports. Getting the status of these tests by reading html would be a better option. Is there a way I can achieve this
http://localhost:8080/job/Test_Sanity/job/Test_Sanity/38//artifact/performanceTestsReports/pcRun106540/Report.html

Comment: Use copy artifact plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and collate these reports to a single location

Answer (score 0):

You might have to zip the reports manually and use extended email plugin to attach the same.

(Note: Extended email plugin can attach only with in the workspace , so you might have to move your zip file to workspace)

Comment: Thank You for your advice.. It seems I need to use custom script to get these reports.